# Remove changes that are in Ready to send for review?

Tags: android, apk, google-developers-console

My application approved and ready to publish yesterday
But today I realized that I made a small mistake, so I go to Google play console and "Remove changes" in Changes are ready to publish section, now my APKs are in "Changes can be sent for review" section, but I dont know how to remove these APKs to reupload fixed APks

Thank in advance

Comment: It seems we can not remove these APKs, we have to upload a new APKs with higher version code and version name? even, these APKs did not publish on Google Play Store yet

Answer (score 0):

The newer APK with the higher version code and version name overwrites the older APK, when it is published to the Play Store

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/223034366/how-to-re-submit-an-apk-file-in-changes-can-be-sent-for-review